# How do I get all the invoice items in my edit page in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

**I am new to laravel, so ignore any mistakes on asking question. I have created the invoice with multiple row table using jquery. Now I need to update the invoice items, so how do I fetch all invoice items in my edit page so I can update it. **

**My tables**
**invoices**

- id
- invoice_no
- subtotal
- discount
- total

**invoice_items**

- id
- invoice_id
- price
- qty
- amount

**Invoice model**

```
public function invoice_items()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\InvoiceItem', 'invoice_id', 'id');
}
```

**InvoiceItem Model**

```
public function invoice()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Invoice');
}
```

If any resources is needed ask me to provide.

```html
public function edit($id)
    {
        $invoice = Invoice::find($id);
        $invoice_items = InvoiceItem::all();
        return view('invoices.edit', compact('invoice', 'invoice_items'));
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried tha way descibed in the documentation? Via magic method: `$invoice->invoice_items` or method `$invoice->invoice_items()->get()`? Remember to use `with` to deal with n+1.

Comment: You have to clear what is an issue? You can not access invoice items, or you dont know how to access data to update after send request (in controller)?

Comment: I have added the items. Now in my edit page i want to get all the items for id 1 from database  as shown in second figure. I don't  know how to do it.

Comment: I suggest to change query to `$invoice = Invoice::with('invoice_items')->find($id)`. Also check the docs (Eloquent, Collection).

Comment: My issue is how to get in blade template.

Comment: Example: `@foreach($invoice->invoice_items as $item)
{{ $item->price }}
@endforeach`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

```
$invoice = Invoice::where('id',$id)->with('invoice_items')->first();
return redirect()->route('your blade route name',compact('invoice',$invoice)))
```

You should get all invoice item that related to invoice .

Comment: Thank you Rezwan. But i don't know how to retrieve all invoice items in table in blade.

Comment: use `dd($invoice)` and you will see that invoice_items will give you a array of invoice_items collection  i think this bellow code will help you 

`{{ $invoice->invoice_items->invoice_items_id}}`

Comment: Thanks Rezwen. I think i got it.

Answer (score 1):

```php
$invoice = Invoice::find($id); // Here you are getting the invoice of a certain ID
$invoice_items = InvoiceItem::all(); // You are getting all the invoices here, not for the specified Invoice
...
```

You should use the method you provided in your Invoice Eloquent `invoices_items` like so

```php
...
$invoices_items = $invoice->invoice_items;
...
```

without `()`, if you do write it like with `()` it must be followed with `get()` so it will be like

```php
$invoices_items = $invoice->invoice_items()->get();
```

Hope this helps

#### Update

@Rezwan mentioned the `->with('invoice_items')` method which is good for performance as it loads the invoices_item with the Invoice in a single query instead of two database queries

Comment: Thanks Emad. I got it.

Answer (score 0):

**This is my controller**

```html
public function edit($id)
    {
        $invoice = Invoice::where('id',$id)->with('invoice_items')->first();
        return view('invoices.edit', compact('invoice'));
    }
```